# Return row containing value

Tags: python, pandas, median

I have a df where the last row is the median.

```py
print(income.head(7))
geo_code                      1       2       3  ...     114     115     116
 1 228 801 -  2 457 600     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN
 1228801 -  2457600       305.0   104.0    74.0  ...     6.0   251.0    15.0
 153601 -  307200        2028.0  2330.0  2341.0  ...   153.0  2256.0  1149.0
 153 801 -  307 600         NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN
 19201 -  38400           408.0   642.0   505.0  ...  2215.0   659.0  1006.0
 19 601 -  38 200           NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN
 1 -  4800                 28.0    38.0    31.0  ...   497.0    80.0   106.0

print(income.tail(3))
geo_code                      1       2       3  ...     114     115     116
 9601 -  19200            167.0   401.0   237.0  ...  1551.0   476.0   583.0
 9601 -  19 600             NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN
median                    408.0   627.0   505.0  ...   497.0   659.0   494.0
```

I need the index (the row) of the median please. How do I return the row that matches the last value in a column?
So the `median` of column `1`, which is `408`, will return: `19201 - 38400`.

Comment: I just noticed, the columns with spaces in the numbers seem to be duplicates. So for the sake of a [mre], you could remove them. See also [reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:-1, 1:].eq(df.iloc[-1, 1:], axis=1).idxmax(), 'geo_code']
```

Output:

```
4            19201 - 38400
0    1 228 801 - 2 457 600
4            19201 - 38400
6                 1 - 4800
4            19201 - 38400
0    1 228 801 - 2 457 600
Name: geo_code, dtype: object
```

If `geo_code` is the Index, you can simplify to:

```
out = df.iloc[:-1].eq(df.iloc[-1], axis=1).idxmax()
```

And if you can have no-matches for some columns you further need to mask:

```
m = df.iloc[:-1].eq(df.iloc[-1], axis=1)

m.idxmax().where(m.any())
```

```
1      19201 - 38400
2                NaN
3      19201 - 38400
114         1 - 4800
115    19201 - 38400
116              NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: In OP's df, `geo_code` is the index. That lets you simplify to `df.iloc[:-1].eq(df.iloc[-1], axis=1).idxmax()` or `df.loc[df.index != 'median'].eq(df.loc['median'], ...`, with the result being indexed by column instead of by row.

Comment: It's worth noting that the data in the question is incomplete, so the two results at row 0 are incorrect.

Comment: @wjandrea good point, I assumed this was a column but the formatting suggests it could be otherwise. I included other options and showed how to mask the values should there be no match

Answer (score 0):

You can find the median row using `.tail(1).squeeze()` and then iterate through the columns, finding the row index where the median value is located. Then a dictionary `median_rows` stores the row indices of the median values for each column. Note that the `.index[0]` part in (`income[column_name] == median_value`) extracts the index (row number) of the first row where the condition is met, assuming that there is only one median value per column.

```
# Calculate the median row for each column
median_row = income.tail(1).squeeze()

# Iterate through columns and find the row with the median value
median_rows = {}
for column_name, median_value in median_row.items():
    median_rows[column_name] = income[income[column_name] == median_value].index[0]

# Print 
for column_name, median_index in median_rows.items():
    print(f"Median of column {column_name}: {median_row[column_name]} is in row {median_index}")
```

Comment: `income.tail(1).squeeze()` can be simplified to `income.iloc[-1]`.